# No me suma la condición si está en true en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, poo

ando haciendo una sencilla aplicación pero en la condición no me suma el +20, seguramente sea alguna tontería pero no lo veo.

acelerar : aumenta la velocidad en 10 si el turbo no está activado y en 20 si está
activado.

Gracias de antemano !

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>examen aviones</title>
</head>

<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        class Aviones { 
            velocidad = 100;
            constructor(velocidad,turbo) {
                this.velocidad = velocidad;
                this.turbo = false;
            }
            acelerar(){
                if(this.turbo = true){
                    this.velocidad += 10;
                }else if(this.turbo = false){
                    this.velocidad += 20;
                }                
            }

            listar(){
                document.write('<br>El avión acelera en  : '+this.velocidad);
            }
        }

        let avion1 = new Aviones(100,false);
        
        avion1.acelerar();
        
        avion1.listar();
               

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Esto: `if(this.turbo = true){` esta mal, debe ser así: `if(this.turbo === true){` o incluso `if(this.turbo){`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No estás usando la operación booleana de comparación '=='.
Código de ejemplo:

```
        if(this.turbo == true){
            this.velocidad += 10;
        }else if(this.turbo == false){
            this.velocidad += 20;
        }
```

O también:

```
        if(this.turbo){
            this.velocidad += 10;
        }else {
            this.velocidad += 20;
        }
```

Incluso:

```
this.velocidad += this.turbo? 10 : 20;
```

Nota: ME parece raro que sume 20 si no hay turbo y 10 si sí.

Comment: gracias por la aclaración @arnau Castellví ya decía yo que no me hacia lo que tenia que hacer !